# Is it possible to get running thread and attach as it's own in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to know if it's possible to attach an already running thread from another Java Instance to another program. For example, if I have a service running that was generated from another program (for example a service that accepts data through a blocking queue and returns data), could I somehow use that same thread for another program, instead of having to create an exact same thread for the same service. I know that you could make it with network sockets but I'd like to do it differently. Also, would it be possible to create a shared memory between two Java instances/VMs?

Comment: No to both questions

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. There are ways of higher level inter-process communication such as RMI, Chronicle Queue, Aeron to name a few.